# How to store min and max marks input by user and output using an if statement

Tags: python

I have been given a program below for calculating the average of a series of exam marks input by the user. Im attempting to add if statements that will then print the minimum and maximum marks input by the user after the average has been printed. I have tried some poor attempts myself which keep giving me invalid syntax errors and cant think of a solution.

```
total = 0.0
count = 0

print("Enter marks one per line")
print("Use a negative number to end")

mark = float(input("Mark: "))

while mark >= 0 :
    total = total + mark
    count = count + 1
    mark = float(input("Mark: "))

if count == 0 :
   print("No marks entered")
else :
   print("The average mark is", round(total/count, 1))
```

The task reads as follows: Modify the program so that it also calculates the minimum and maximum marks. You will need to use two new variables, mini and maxi, to keep track of the smallest and largest values entered so far. These should be initialised to the first mark entered, so this needs to be done after the initial input but before the loop. Inside the loop you will need to check whether the newly-entered mark is smaller than mini or larger than maxi, and if so, update the value of the appropriate variable - use if statements to do this. Add another print statement after the output of the average to output a message such as

The largest mark was 82.5 and the smallest mark was 17.3

Answer (score 0):

Use `list` to store marks like below, it will make your life easier.

```
print("Enter marks one per line")
print("Use a negative number to end")

total = 0.0
marks = []
mark = float(input("Mark: "))

while mark >= 0 :
    marks.append(mark)
    total = total + mark
    mark = float(input("Mark: "))

if not marks:
    print("No records present")
else:
    print("Average Marks:", total/len(marks))
    print("maximum marks:", max(marks))
    print("minimum marks", min(marks))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read to list and use list functions like `sum` to sum marks, `max` to find the largest mark and `min` to find the smallest mark:

```
print("Enter marks one per line")
print("Use a negative number to end")

marks = []

while True :
    mark = float(input("Mark: "))
    if mark < 0:
        break
    marks.append(mark)

if len(marks) == 0 :
   print("No marks entered")
else :
   print("The average mark is ", sum(marks) // len(marks))
   print("The largest mark is ", max(marks))
   print("The smallest mark is ", min(marks))
```

Answer (score 0):

> You will need to use two new variables, mini and maxi, to keep track of the smallest and largest values entered so far. These should be initialised to the first mark entered

This is straightforward.  After the initial input, initialize these two variables:

```
mark = float(input("Mark: "))
mini = mark
maxi = mark
```

> Inside the loop you will need to check whether the newly-entered mark is smaller than mini or larger than maxi, and if so, update the value of the appropriate variable

This is also straightforward:

```
while mark >= 0:
    if mark > maxi:
        maxi = mark
    if mark < mini:
        mini = mark
    total = total + mark
    count = count + 1
    mark = float(input("Mark: "))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try now

Comment: All works well. I did the same up until the if statements where I got a bit lost.